# High level Rails patterns: organizing views around nested doc, chapter, page hierarchy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns, nested-resources

What's the **Rails way** of displaying the views for a somewhat deeply nested hierarchy? Seems like a simple question but try to bear with me and maybe someone will understand (and hopefully clear up) my confusion.

My app is a simple hierarchy, of sorts (simplified more so for purposes of this discussion):

- At the top I have an **index of documents**
- click one and get a view with more details about the **Document** including a **list(index) of its chapters**
- click a chapter from that list and get **a Page** with previous & next links and similar **list of chapters** in the margin with current one highlighted.

Simple enough but my question is what's the rails way to:

1. nest the resources so they're not too deep?
2. structure the views?

The reason I ask something seemingly so basic is because, starting with the first click I'm viewing a 'Document' (`document#show`) but also the chapters (`chapters#index`) that it contains. So, in which of the two *should* the view be built?

Same with the next click where I'm looking at the beginning of a Chapter. That could be the `chapters#show` or `pages#index` action. Though, conceivably I guess it could (and maybe should) also be handled by `pages#show`.

Thoughts? Am I over thinking things? (likely)

Answer (score 4):

#### Routes

You can set up your routes like this to take advantage of Rails' built in nested resources:

```
resources :documents, :only => [:index, :show] do
  resources :chapters, :only => :show do
    resources :pages, :only => :show
  end
end
```

This is roughly equivalent to setting up these custom routes:

```
get '/documents' => 'documents#index',
    :as => 'documents'
get '/documents/:id' => 'documents#show',
    :as => 'document'
get '/documents/:document_id/chapters/:id' => 'chapters#show',
    :as => 'document_chapter'
get '/documents/:document_id/chapters/:chapter_id/pages/:id' => 'pages#show',
    :as => 'document_chapter_page'
```

If the URLs are a little longer and more cumbersome than you had hoped for, or you want to use custom parameters (e.g. identifying pages by number and not by ID), you can always write custom routes instead:

```
resources :documents, :only => [:index, :show]
get '/documents/:document_id/:id' => 'chapters#show',
    :as => 'document_chapter'
get '/documents/:document_id/:chapter_id/:page' => 'pages#show',
    :as => 'document_chapter_page'
```

See the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information.

#### Controllers

You don't want a user to be able to visit a chapter directly, instead they should see the first page of the chapter. However, it's arguably useful for chapter URLs to work without a page number (especially if page numbers refer to the position in a document and not the position in a chapter).

You could therefore redirect from the chapters controller's `show` action to the first page:

```
class ChaptersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to [chapter.document, chapter, chapter.pages.first]
  end
end
```

#### Views

There are two approaches you could take to sharing the list of chapters between different views:

1. Use Rails' built in support for rendering a collection of model objects.  In your `views/documents/show.html.erb` and `views/chapters/show.html.erb` you can include something like the following (I'm assuming each action sets a `@document` variable):

   ```
   <ol>
     <%= render @document.chapters %>
   </ol>
   ```

   Rails will look for a partial view called `views/chapters/_chapter.html.erb`, and render it for each of the chapters. It could look like this:

   ```
   <li><%= link_to chapter, [chapter.document, chapter] %></li>
   ```
2. Share the whole list in a single partial. For example, you could add the following to `views/documents/show.html.erb` and `views/chapters/show.html.erb`:

   ```
   <%= render 'chapters/list', :chapters => @document.chapters %>
   ```

   And create a partial view called `views/chapters/_list.html.erb`:

   ```
   <ol>
     <% chapters.each do |chapter| %>
       <li><%= link_to chapter, [chapter.document, chapter] %></li>
     <% end %>
   </ol>
   ```

See the section on [Using Partials in the Layouts and Rendering guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I've read more than once that nesting shouldn't be abused,  2 levels is obviously fine,  three levels if it makes sense,  but anything over three levels, and you probably need to rethink things.

You could do with three levels of nesting,  i.e.

/docs/:id/:chapter/:page

But it might also make sense to do this

/docs/:id/:page

i.e. directly reference a page of a document,  not caring to specify the chapter

If chapter is a number,  and page is a number,  how would your routing differentiate, i.e.

/docs/1001/1

Is that page 1 of doc 1001 ?  Or chapter 1 of doc 1001?

Just playing devil's advocate,  showing potential shortcomings when you try and nest deeply.

I think the most natural thing is:

```
'/docs' => 'docs#index'  # show all docs
'/docs/:id'  => 'docs#show' # show all chapters in a doc
'/docs/:id/chapter/:chpt' => 'docs#show_chapter' # show all pages in a chapter in a doc
'/docs/:id/:page'  => 'docs#show'  # show a page in a doc

the show actions would have:
if params[:page]
  # show page specified
else
  # show all chapters
end

the order of the routes is important
```

The reason I'd recommend this is because book/page query semantics is probably more common than book/chapter/page.

The associations would be:

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
  has_many :chapters
end
```

I wouldn't expose end_page in the routing,  I'd just tack '?endpage=X'  on any route that accepts :page, so for example in the show action:

```
if params[:page]
  if params[:end_page]
    # show pages :page through :end_page
  else
    # show single :page
  end
else
  # show all chapters
end
```